# Laravel vuejs routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

What am trying to do is to build a laravel axios routes which have query parameters that is

a sample request looks like

```
 axios.get("/user-management/permissions?role=" + this.role)
```

so the aboe generates

```
localhost:8000/user-management/permissions?role=admin"//role value changes
```

Now am stuck at setting the actual routes in the laravel routes

I have the following

```
Route::get('permissions/{role}', "PermissionsController@PermissionRole");
```

THe above route is never executed.How do i go about setting up my laravel routes to have the query string parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misunderstood:

The route `Route::get('permissions/{role}', "PermissionsController@PermissionRole");` will respond to requests of the form `/user-management/permissions/admin`

You don't need to specify the expected query string. You need to have this route:

```
Route::get('permissions', "PermissionsController@PermissionRole");
```

Then in your controller:

```
function PermissionRole(Request $request) {
       $role= $request->get("role"); //admin ?
}
```

If you want to add the role as part of the URL you can do:

```
Route::get('permissions/{role}', "PermissionsController@PermissionRole");
```

Then you can access the role in the action:

```
function PermissionRole(Request $request, $role) {
      //$role variable name matches the route name
}
```

However you can also make it mandatory by using validation:

```
function PermissionRole(Request $request) {
       $this->validate($request->all(), [ 
              "role" => "required|in:admin,user" //example
       ]);
}
```

Comment: okay, i see my mistake but is it possible to build routes with parameters am trying to build an api where people will pass in query parameters eg: ?role=""?date=""?newitem=""

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI not with query string parameters, but you can perform [Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation) on the `Request` object or even override it with your own route specific class (using [Form validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#form-request-validation)

Comment: thanks also based on the way youve put it i cannot enforce the role to be mandatory so adding adding /{role}  makes it mandatory but now i cannot fetch the mandatory parameter ow do i go about this.

Comment: i see where its going wrong to fetch ive had to change  $request->get("role")  to  $request->route("role"). Update your answer on the same.

Comment: Updated with an alternative way. But I stil l think validation is better. There's a lot more rules you can impose other than required. You can validate to only accept certain values or number etc.

Answer (score 1):

route:

```
Route::get('permissions/{role}', "PermissionsController@PermissionRole");
```

Is never executed because you should have link like this:

```
localhost:8000/user-management/permissions/admin  //admin is role
```